# C# ASP.NET Checkbox selected single value

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, checkbox, checkboxlist

I am  trying to get selected value from my checkbox (talking about only single result/check), I want to get that value on event onClick on my button, and not only checkbox I also got there two dropdown lists that I am taking also selected value out of, and when I click my button, I get values from dropdown lists and I can't get value from checkboxlist and I dont know why because I set allready before on page load source and eveything seems to look fine but I can't get value :/

Here is the code:

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var dropDown_one= Convert.ToInt32(dropOne.SelectedValue); //THIS IS OK
       var dropDown_two = Convert.ToInt32(dropTwo.SelectedValue);//THIS IS OK
       var checkBox = Convert.ToInt32(checkBox.SelectedValue); //<- here I got error, because I am trying to convert "" value to int

    }
```

and on page load I dId this:

```
checkBox.DataSource =SomethingFromDatabase();
        checkBox.DataTextField = "Name";
        checkBox.DataValueField = "ID";
        checkBox.DataBind();
```

So I got values from Database and I am able to check them, but when I click my button I got error because checkboxlist says that its value is "" so like I did not select anything even if I did.. :/

Thanks guys,
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Page_Load` event handler is executed on every postback. If you call your data binding code each time, the CheckBoxList is cleared and refilled, and the selections that you had made are lost.

The solution to this problem is to bind the data inside a `if (!IsPostBack)` conditional block:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        checkBox.DataSource = SomethingFromDatabase();
        checkBox.DataTextField = "Name";
        checkBox.DataValueField = "ID";
        checkBox.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is answer to this problem, but I will try soon when I come back home and I will leave a reply if it's ok! and mark it as an answer :) Thanks

Comment: This was the answer! Thanks a lot @ConnorsFan! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Checkbox is not in the disabled state since it will return NULL in a disabled state and convert it to Int will throw the error. So check NULL for check box value and convert it.